# How to change from gnome deskop to lxde desktop in fedora 23 in virtualbox

Tags: linux, ubuntu, virtualbox, fedora, gnome

I have just installed lxde desktop in fedora. I have installed default gnome desktop. Now i can not change gnome to lxde. In Ubuntu in time user account logging there was option that we can choose our certain desktop. But this is automatic login, no password needed to enter. How i can chose the desktop that i want to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open `gnome-control-center` (or Settings) and go to the Users tab where you can switch the Automatic Login handler. Then, when you log out you will be prompted for password and you will be able to choose other desktop environments.

Comment: how i can set password for a account if not password is set for it

Comment: In the same window click on the field _Password_.